# How to observe changes to the items contained by an NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, nsarraycontroller, key-value-observing

I have an object containing an `NSMutableArray` called `pointValue` and several methods including `setPointValue`. When the latter method is invoked it triggers another method `saveTable` which saves `pointValue` to a file (its a csv but does matter not here as the save methods work).
I now have nib file which contains a `NSTableView` and `NSArrayController` which is connected to the array in the object. 
With a button in the nib is pressed it triggers the `NSArrayController` `remove:` method, removing the selected item, accessing the `setPointValue` which saves the new array.

This all works perfectly, my problem begins when I edit a cell in the table manually and press enter, the array is changed but `setPointValue` is not triggered and thus the array is not saved to file.

I am absolutely god-smacked why setPointValue is not evoked. Do i have to bind the array control or the table columns to something?

Comment: There's no such thing as an `NSArrayControl`.  Do you mean `NSArrayController`?  A "control" is *very* different from a "controller".

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973208/how-to-get-notified-of-changes-to-models-via-an-nsarraycontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NSArrayController is only observing its content array. You want to observe values of the objects *in* that array, which is not the same thing.

I'd strongly encourage you to read all the documentation on [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) and [Cocoa Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html).

You'll see that you'll need to observe items as they're added to your setPointValue array and stop observing them when they're removed. You can do this by creating [indexed collection accessor methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973208/how-to-get-notified-of-changes-to-models-via-an-nsarraycontroller) for your setPointValue and setting up or tearing down observing for items added and removed therein. You'll also need to react to [receiving notification of the changes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:) to your observed items to trigger your save method.

Sosborn is correct - this is effectively a [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973208/how-to-get-notified-of-changes-to-models-via-an-nsarraycontroller). See the accepted answer the OP provided himself for the most direct solution (better than my original answer to this question).

Comment: I edited your answer to include the fourth link. Can you verify that I added the correct one, please?

Comment: It's the correct link, thanks, but I probably should've left that sentence out when I amended my answer to point to the dup's answer. It's a better way to handle things.